# JqGrid Edit Function Not Working But The Parameter is Sent

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jqgrid

i have some problem that using jqgrid as jquery framework.

In my case, i have some table which is CRUD function that connect to a table let say departments

in this table there are two id: idms_department, department (name). The idms_department is auto increment column.

here's my jqgrid syntax

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            //alert("start");
            jQuery("#departments").jqGrid({
                mtype:'GET',
                url:'functions/get_dept.php',
                editurl:'functions/edit_dept.php',
                datatype: "JSON",
                colNames:['Department ID','Department'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'idms_department',index:'idms_department', width:150, editable:false, key:true},
                    {name:'department',index:'department', width:800,editable:true}     
                ],
                loadComplete: function () {
                alert("OK");
                },    
                loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '\n' +
                          'textStatus: ' + textStatus + '\n' +
                          'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
                    alert('HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                },
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[5,10,15],
                pager: '#pager-departments',
                sortname: 'idms_department',
                viewrecords: true,
                jsonReader: {repeatitems: true, idms_department: "idms_department" },
                sortorder: "asc",
                caption:"MSC Departments"
            });
            jQuery("#departments").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager-departments',{edit:true,add:true,del:true},{closeAfterEdit:true},{closeAfterAdd:true},{},{closeAfterSearch:true},{});
            jQuery("#departments").jqGrid('gridResize',{minWidth:350,maxWidth:850,minHeight:80, maxHeight:350});
            //alert("end");
            //start navigation system
            $('#navigation-bar').collapsible({
                effect: 'none',
        initialCollapse: true
    });
            //end navigation system 
        });
```

i can add new data using add dialog in jqgrid, but when i want to edit the form, it doesn't editable.

The problem is the id i think. Before, the editable for idms_department is set to editable:true, the working fine, but when i make it editable:false, because, the user can't add new id himself, so i make it editable:false, and the row is gone from dialog.

I have get response from my firebug, it shows that the function is sending the right data, but, the data is unchanged.

The function of edit php goes here:

```
  if($oper == 'edit'){
   $deptid = $_POST['idms_department'];
   echo $deptid;
   $deptnm = $_POST['department'];
   $upt = "UPDATE ms_department SET idms_department = '$deptid', department = '$deptnm' WHERE idms_department = '$deptid'";
if(mysql_query($upt)){
    "Edited Successfully";
} else {
    die("Error Edit : " .mysql_error());
}
   mysql_close();
}
```

is there anything wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why you want to make autoincremental filed `idms_department` editable by user? By the way it could not only follow to conflicts, but it could be just not permitted by the database. In Microsoft SQL Server which I use one have to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ms_department ON` before `UPDATE` which change autoincrelemt column and use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ms_department OFF` after the `UPDATE`. I don't use MySQL, but it can exist the same problem too.

Comment: yes, because of that, i just set the editable to false, but it doesn't updated, even tough the parameter is sent correctly.

Comment: You use `UPDATE ms_department SET idms_department = '$deptid', department = '$deptnm' WHERE idms_department = '$deptid'";`. So you still try to change `idms_department`. Why?

Comment: yes, i have delete the words idms_department = '$deptid', but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jaGrid send rowid as `id`, but you use

```
$deptid = $_POST['idms_department'];
```

and later `WHERE idms_department = '$deptid'"` in the `UPDATE`. You have to change the above statement to

```
$deptid = $_POST['id'];
```

or to use `prmNames: {id: "idms_department"}` option of jqGrid to rename `"id"` variable which will be sent during editing to `"idms_department"`.

Comment: hi oleg! aha, i've forgot to change the id! thanks for reminding. :D

Comment: hi @oleg, sorry to bother you, can u look to my question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656223/jqgrid-show-error-message-from-server-response perhaps it's simple answer. thanks

Comment: @randytan: Sorry, but I'm very busy now (at least today and tomorrow) with my main job. I have to finish one project. If you'll not find the solution of your problem till the time I'll try to help you. You can remind me in two days about the problem if it will be not solved.

Comment: it's okay oleg. Thanks for replying.