# Show Error Message from Server Response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have some problems with jqGrid.

I've added a method that validates users input. If the department exist then it will show a warning message, "Department is Exist!"

Here's my jqGrid code:

```
afterSubmit: function(response, postdata){
                    var res = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                    if (res === "1") {
                        return [false,"Department Already Exist"];
                    } else {
                        return [true,"Sucess"];
                    }
                }
```

And my php add method:

```
if($oper == 'add') {
 $deptid = $_POST['idms_department'];
 $deptnm = $_POST['department'];
 if(checkUser($deptnm) == "FALSE"){
   return "1";
 } else {
   $ins = "INSERT INTO ms_department(department) VALUES('$deptnm')";
    if(mysql_query($ins)){
        "Success INSERT msDept";
    } else {
        die("Failed : " .mysql_error());
    }
}
     mysql_close();
} else .... (another operation)
```

The message itself is not showing. How do you use the afterSubmit method properly?
thanks

**UPDATE**

i've change the method to

```
  crudMessage = function(response,postdata){
                var res   = response.responseText; // response text is returned from server.
                 if (res === "1") {
                    return [false,"Department Already Exist"];
                } else {
                    return [true,"Sucess"];
                }
             }
```

then removing the afterSubmit from the jqgrid body and add this line into the jqgrid navigation:

```
 jQuery("#departments").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager-departments',{edit:true,add:true,del:true}, {closeAfterEdit: true},{beforeShowForm: function(form) { $('#idms_department', form).hide(); },closeAfterAdd:true},{afterSubmit: crudMessage},{closeAfterSearch:true},{});
```

here's newest php syntax:

```
 include 'configuration.php';

 function checkDepartment($department){
   $query = "SELECT department FROM ms_department WHERE department ='$department' LIMIT 1";
   $result= mysql_query($query);
   return mysql_num_rows($result);
}

if($oper == 'add') {
 $deptid = $_POST['idms_department'];
 $deptnm = $_POST['department'];
 if(checkDepartment($deptnm) == 1){
      echo '1';
  } else {
    $ins = "INSERT INTO ms_department(department) VALUES('$deptnm')";
     if(mysql_query($ins)){
        "Success INSERT msDept";
       } else {
        die("Failed : " . mysql_error());
    }
  }
   mysql_close();
 } else 
   if($oper == 'edit'){ ....
```

Comment: You don't show any code where that message "Department is Exist!" (which is by the way terrible English) is supposed to be shown or where it is triggered in the first place.
I also wonder if your checkUser function really returns the string "FALSE". You'd better return the boolean false

Comment: I think that you have to implement `errorTextFormat` additionally to `afterSubmit` because you use `die`. I'm not a PHP developer. Could you insert **full HTTP response** (inclusive all HTTP headers and the body) in case `return "1"`. You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Developer Tools of Internet Explorer (press F12 to start) or Chrome to catch full HTTP traffic.

Comment: hi @Oleg, thanks commenting, if i submit a new value which is not available in database, then it is success. I've implement some validation method to check whether the value is already exist or not. If it's success it will post: 200 OK

Comment: I'm just not a PHP developer, but some parts of the code looks suspected. For example `if(checkUser($deptnm) == "FALSE")` contains `return "1";` (no `echo` or something like that). The case `if(mysql_query($ins)){...}` contains `"Success INSERT msDept";` **without** `echo` or `return`. So I'd like to see full exact HTTP response from the trace of HTTP traffic. Can one really see `"1"`, `"Success INSERT msDept"` or other texts in response body? Is the call of `$.parseJSON` required on `response.responseText`?

Comment: the response body is throwing nothing. I just change the code into echo "1" and it prints 1 on the body. Here's the firebug response:
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Length 0
Content-Type text/html
Date Mon, 15 Jul 2013 15:29:17 GMT
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100

Comment: @Oleg, if you're not busy, can we discuss privately? i can send you the url to access with. thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your code, why are you expecting `res.insertStatus`? From the snippet of PHP code that you provided, it seems you would want to write:

```
var res = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
if (res === "User Already Exist!") {
```

Or maybe I am missing something? Have you tried debugging your code?

That should explain why the `alert` is not appearing.

---

Also, for what its worth, according to the [jqGrid documentation for form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing):

> **afterSubmit**
>   fires after response has been received from server. Typically used to display status from server (e.g., the data is successfully saved or the save cancelled for server-side editing reasons). Receives as parameters the data returned from the request and an array of the posted values of type id=value1,value2.
>
> When used this event should return array with the following items `[success, message, new_id]`where
>
> success is a boolean value if true the process continues, if false a error message appear and all other processing is stopped. (message is ignored if success is true).
>
> new_id can be used to set the new row id in the grid when we are in add mode. 
>        afterSubmit : function(response, postdata) 
>       { 
>       … 
>       return [success,message,new_id] 
>       }

Based on these docs, your final code should remove the `alert` and just use jqGrid directly:

```
if (res === "User Already Exist!") {
    return [false, "TODO: put your error message here"];
}
```

Comment: hi @justin, i've update my question. But still error message is not working. Is there any possibilities? thanks

Comment: Try `if (res == "1") {` with `==`. Also, have you verified your JSON response is what you expect?

Comment: how to verified the JSON response ?

Comment: Use a JavaScript debugger. A good first choice is Firefox and Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/). Or you can just use the developer tools on Chrome (IE?). In any case, you can see the XHR (AJAX) request go out, and the response sent back to the browser. You can also set breakpoints and debug in real time, if you want.

Comment: hi @Justin, yes, the response from the server is 1 if exist and 0 if not exist.

Comment: Try using == in your JavaScript.